# Performance implications of client-side rendering and Fibers in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

A lot of people have commented on how Fibers (which gives you synchronous code in Node.js) breaks compatibility with 99% of npm packages. I'm more interested in the performance implications.

Does this undo the "Node.js is really fast, look, it's asynchronous/event-based!" argument? What is the practical implication of the Meteor team baking in Fibers?

Also, after deploying a huge rewrite where pages were rendered on the client-side, Twitter [reversed their decision](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html) in favor of serving HTML from the server to improve page load times. What does this mean for Meteor's potential performance limitations (especially on first page load)?

Comment: `A lot of` and `99%` are weasel words...

Comment: Sorry, Tom. As far as `a lot of` goes, it was a complaint that I disregarded, but there is certainly precedent for this. As a starting place, see [a competitor's argument](http://blog.derbyjs.com/2012/04/14/our-take-on-derby-vs-meteor/) against Fibers. And according to a quick search on http://search.npmjs.org/ , 13 of 11320 packages support (mention) Fibers. So 99.99885% of npm packages would probably (weasel word?!) be incompatible.

Comment: I'm not really into Fibers besides having followed its Windows support (to get Meteor running on Windows), but doesn't Fibers just allow you to wrap a call to such modules and make the call block? As in... You could place `Fiber.yield();` in the callback and then wrap the call in a `Fiber(...).run()`. Because I think the whole point is that packages don't have to be made compatible as there is no way for them to be incompatible (other than whether they are *using* it).

Comment: Also, Meteor has been MIT licensed for a while so that article is outdated. In any case, if you want you could try to contact the developer of Fibers wrt the compatibility as well as the Meteor developers wrt if this results in any compatibility. Because as far as I've seen, I saw no incompatibility problems yet. But given that Meteor is fairly new, it's also possible that they might not have ran into big hurdles yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development team is planning on implementing server-side rendering to work around the first page load issue as well as to support search engines, by sending the initial data that is shown to the user as part of the HTML he gets to see the initial data while still retaining all the rest.